# Express async route logging undefined after await

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, node-mysql

I am writing an Express endpoint in Typescript to update a user's password in the database, but having some trouble with multiple queries/synchronous code.

My problem is right now I am trying to await the return of a function but it doesn't seem to be *awaiting*.

My route looks like this:

```
router.put("/:userId", validateUser, async (req: any, res: Response) => {
    const result: any = await updatePassword(req.body.password, req.body.confirmPassword, req.params.userId);
    console.log(result) //LOGS UNDEFINED????
    if (result.status !== 200) res.status(result.status).send({ message: result.message, code: result.code });
    res.send("Success!");
});
```

and that `updatePassword` function looks like this:

```
const updatePassword = async (password: string, confirmPassword: string, userId: string) => {
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
        return { status: 409,  message: Errors.mismatchingPasswordMessage, code: Errors.mismatchingPasswordCode };
    }

    const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
    //update the password in the DB
    pool.query("UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE userId = ?", [hashedPassword, userId], (err: MysqlError, result: any) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return { status: 500,  message: err.message, code: err.code };
        }
        if (result.changedRows !== 1) {
            return { status: 500,  message: "Password could not be updated!" };
        }

        return { status: 200 };
    });
}
```

Why is this the route not correctly *awaiting* the result of `updatePassword`??

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: looks like you are missing a comma between the last 2 params to `updatePassword` call

Comment: @AMacdonald just a mistake I made when inputing the example code, not actually in my real code. Also wouldn't have had anything to do with the problem I am having

Comment: You're mixing up promises and callbacks. You can't return anything from pool.query callback. So updatePassword returns undefined.

Comment: @EstusFlask ok...so to fix I need not use pool.query()? How else would I update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you're mixing async/await and callback style in this part

```
 pool.query("UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE userId = ?", [hashedPassword, userId], (err: MysqlError, result: any) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return { status: 500,  message: err.message, code: err.code };
        }
        if (result.changedRows !== 1) {
            return { status: 500,  message: "Password could not be updated!" };
        }

        return { status: 200 };
    });
```

The function `updatePassword` jumps directly to the next line after this block, which is nothing. So it returns `undefined`.

You need to replace this block with async/await code. Something like :

```
try {
       const result = await pool.query("UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE userId = ?", [hashedPassword, userId]);
        
        if (result.changedRows !== 1) {
            return { status: 500,  message: "Password could not be updated!" };
        }

        return { status: 200 };
}
catch (err){

       console.log(err);
       return { status: 500,  message: err.message, code: err.code };
        
}
```

Comment: Ah yes. That makes sense. I actually originally had something like this but I was getting a circular JSON error. Now it appears to be working. Thanks for the answer